# Turn string back into an array

Tags: php, arrays

My PHP script gets the content from another site via `file_get_contents()`. 
The site im grabbing the content from only has an array thats being displayed with `print_r()` looking like this.

```
Array
(
 [0] => apple
 [1] => 10
 [2] => 6
 )
```

Now on my Page i want the grabbed content to be an array and not string? 
Is there anyway todo this ive been searching around for quite some time now and cant find a solution.

Comment: What does `var_dump()` give you?

Comment: Is the other site in your control?

Comment: string(66) "
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 6
)
"

Comment: @vivek_23 yes it is

Comment: @Freddy789 Why not send a json string from there?

Comment: How todo that? Can  you maybe give an example?

Comment: @Freddy789 See [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php);